# Error creating Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, server, localhost

I have some assignments where i have to make a Ajax call to run the server. I used Eclipse  and create my local host using Apache tomcat when i start to create a dynamic project an error message comes telling me:

[image: screen print]

it doesn't allow me to create dynamic project.

if someone here know the answer .It would be great

Comment: Have you tried to read the message in the dialog (third line on your screenshot)?

Comment: yes . i know that was the problem how can i solve it.i'm a beginner with zero knowledge.

Comment: Have you tried installing Java version 1.6 or newer onto your system?